# How to automatically add dots when user enter date?

Tags: angular, date

I am creating input field for date in angular. I want angular to automatically enter dot when I insert date like 02 (automatically .) 04 (automatically .) 2019

Comment: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask

Comment: Show us please what do you have already tried to achieve it.
There is also primeng´s inputmask, see https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputmask. To do yourself you colud check on every keypressed the last two chars. If two numbers add a point.

Answer (score 2):

so far [ngx-mask](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask) one of the best angular masks ,and you can build a pattern easly this pattern will roek for date `00.00.0000` , 0 for digits (0-9)

```
   <input mask="00.00.0000" formControlName="date"  [dropSpecialCharacters]="false">
```

> if you set dropSpecialCharacters to false this will remove the dot character , check the repo for all possible options

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-separator-ccaphj)

Installing

```
npm install --save ngx-mask
```

import `NgxMaskModule` in app module

```
import {NgxMaskModule} from 'ngx-mask'


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule , ReactiveFormsModule , NgxMaskModule.forRoot({
    showMaskTyped : true,
  }) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Maybe angular version or something is not correct.

Comment: What version of angular are you using , did you check the example

Comment: Yes I did. Angular 7.

Comment: I already use it in angular 7 and it working fine even the demo run on angular 7 ,check the repo how to install this package

Comment: @user10033337 I have add installation steps during creating the demo , hope this will help 

Answer (score 0):

check this [ngx-mask](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask)

you need to initialize to null since it is a interface then just follow the doc

```
import { NgxMaskModule, IConfig } from 'ngx-mask';
export const options: Partial<IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>) = null;
```